# Flutter Freezed - Object has two of every field

Tags: flutter, dart, freezed

All of my objects in the app that use [@freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) are creating 2 of each field.

I'm on `freezed: ^0.12.7`

When I copy paste the example from the docs of version 0.12.7:

```
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'x.freezed.dart';

@freezed
abstract class Person implements _$Person {
  // uses implements instead of with
  const Person._(); // Added constructor
  const factory Person(String name, {int age}) = _Person;

  void method() {
    print('hello world');
  }
}
```

The double up occurs:

[image]

***EDIT:*** I have just confirmed the exact same behaviour in `freezed 0.14.1+2`.

With copy and paste from official docs:

```
@freezed
class Person with _$Person {
  const Person._(); // Added constructor
  const factory Person(String name, {int? age}) = _Person;

  void method() {
    print('hello world');
  }
}
```

Comment: i'm still getting this on freezed: ^1.1.0
are you still getting this on the latest versions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting a good generation of `Person` object from your code. There could be some error related to your `part` statement. Whenever creating a new class, use `@freeze` with `part 'name.freezed.dart'`, so in this case it should be:

```dart
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'person.freezed.dart';

@freezed
abstract class Person implements _$Person {
  // uses implements instead of with
  const Person._(); // Added constructor
  const factory Person(String name, {int age}) = _Person;

  void method() {
    print('hello world');
  }
}
```

Here's my code generation after running `flutter pub run build_runner build` command:

```dart
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND
// ignore_for_file: deprecated_member_use, deprecated_member_use_from_same_package, use_function_type_syntax_for_parameters, unnecessary_const, avoid_init_to_null, invalid_override_different_default_values_named, prefer_expression_function_bodies

part of 'person.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// FreezedGenerator
// **************************************************************************

T _$identity<T>(T value) => value;

/// @nodoc
class _$PersonTearOff {
  const _$PersonTearOff();

// ignore: unused_element
  _Person call(String name, {int age}) {
    return _Person(
      name,
      age: age,
    );
  }
}

/// @nodoc
// ignore: unused_element
const $Person = _$PersonTearOff();

/// @nodoc
mixin _$Person {
  String get name;
  int get age;

  @JsonKey(ignore: true)
  $PersonCopyWith<Person> get copyWith;
}

/// @nodoc
abstract class $PersonCopyWith<$Res> {
  factory $PersonCopyWith(Person value, $Res Function(Person) then) =
      _$PersonCopyWithImpl<$Res>;
  $Res call({String name, int age});
}

/// @nodoc
class _$PersonCopyWithImpl<$Res> implements $PersonCopyWith<$Res> {
  _$PersonCopyWithImpl(this._value, this._then);

  final Person _value;
  // ignore: unused_field
  final $Res Function(Person) _then;

  @override
  $Res call({
    Object name = freezed,
    Object age = freezed,
  }) {
    return _then(_value.copyWith(
      name: name == freezed ? _value.name : name as String,
      age: age == freezed ? _value.age : age as int,
    ));
  }
}

/// @nodoc
abstract class _$PersonCopyWith<$Res> implements $PersonCopyWith<$Res> {
  factory _$PersonCopyWith(_Person value, $Res Function(_Person) then) =
      __$PersonCopyWithImpl<$Res>;
  @override
  $Res call({String name, int age});
}

/// @nodoc
class __$PersonCopyWithImpl<$Res> extends _$PersonCopyWithImpl<$Res>
    implements _$PersonCopyWith<$Res> {
  __$PersonCopyWithImpl(_Person _value, $Res Function(_Person) _then)
      : super(_value, (v) => _then(v as _Person));

  @override
  _Person get _value => super._value as _Person;

  @override
  $Res call({
    Object name = freezed,
    Object age = freezed,
  }) {
    return _then(_Person(
      name == freezed ? _value.name : name as String,
      age: age == freezed ? _value.age : age as int,
    ));
  }
}

/// @nodoc
class _$_Person extends _Person {
  const _$_Person(this.name, {this.age})
      : assert(name != null),
        super._();

  @override
  final String name;
  @override
  final int age;

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Person(name: $name, age: $age)';
  }

  @override
  bool operator ==(dynamic other) {
    return identical(this, other) ||
        (other is _Person &&
            (identical(other.name, name) ||
                const DeepCollectionEquality().equals(other.name, name)) &&
            (identical(other.age, age) ||
                const DeepCollectionEquality().equals(other.age, age)));
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode =>
      runtimeType.hashCode ^
      const DeepCollectionEquality().hash(name) ^
      const DeepCollectionEquality().hash(age);

  @JsonKey(ignore: true)
  @override
  _$PersonCopyWith<_Person> get copyWith =>
      __$PersonCopyWithImpl<_Person>(this, _$identity);
}

abstract class _Person extends Person {
  const _Person._() : super._();
  const factory _Person(String name, {int age}) = _$_Person;

  @override
  String get name;
  @override
  int get age;
  @override
  @JsonKey(ignore: true)
  _$PersonCopyWith<_Person> get copyWith;
}
```

Comment: That's the exact same generated code as mine. I think if you inspected in a debugger you would have the same issue.

Comment: are you sure that's not a debugger issue? By inspecting through a breakpoint you get the same inspected value?